# Swift 3 conversion hex to Int8 like in java

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a problem with converting hex values to Int8 in Swift 3.

In Java it looks like this:

(`bytes` is a `byte` array in Java and `Int8` array in Swift)

**Java:**

```
bytes[0] = (byte) 0xFB
```

**Swift3:**

```
bytes[0] = Int8(0xFB)
```

When I try this in Swift, Xcode throws this error:

> error: integer overflows when converted from 'Int' to 'Int8'

Comment: Actually bytes are `UInt8` in Swift.

Comment: I rewrite app from java so i need to recreate this operation in Swift. Result this operation in Java will be -6.

Comment: Are you trying to create an `Int8` with a *bit pattern* of 0xFB? If so, there's an initialiser for that ;)

Comment: Thx for help :) 
Bit pattern is the solution. I used simple framework [Bitter](https://github.com/uraimo/Bitter) to fast and simple convert Hex to Int8.

Answer (score 2):

An `Int8` can store a value from **-128** (`Int8.min`) to **127** (`Int8.max`).

You value `0xFB` is **251** so it cannot be represented with an `Int8`.

Comment: I know that Int8 in Swift have range from -128 to 127.

Comment: @WujoFefer: So why are you trying to put `251` inside a type value that cannot exceed `127`?

Comment: I rewrite app to controll some devices from Java and i need this value to send as message. I just need simple conversion Hex to Int8 like in java.

Comment: @WujoFefer: As I said, you cannot put __251__ inside a `Int8`. So pick another type like `UInt8`

Comment: Whole communication is based on the bytes in Java. This creates some problems like this.